# how to implement a loop with conditional breaks in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to find out the first n that satisfies [image: f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{1/(k*k+2k)}>=2.99/4.0]. It's a simple and easy stuff if I use another language, like c/c++, but I don't know how to implement it in Haskell.

```
#include <iostream>
long double term(int k) { return 1.0/(k*k+2.0*k); }
int main() {
    long double total = 0.0;
    for (int k=1;;k++) {
        total += term(k);
        if (total>=2.99/4.0) {
            std::cout << k << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I used dropWhile with an ordered list and take 1 to pick up the first one.

```
term k = 1.0/(k*k+2.0*k)
termSum n = sum $ take n $ map term [1..]
main = do
  let [(n,val)] = take 1 $ dropWhile (\(a,b)->b <= 2.99/4.0) $ map (\n->(n,termSum n)) [1..]
  print n
```

I know it's horrible. What is the best and intuitive way to write this?

Re:
Thank you for the great answers! The one using fix function seems to be the fastest in my machine (Redhat 6.4 64bit / 80GB memory)

method#0 take 1 and dropWhile (my initial implementation)

```
threshold=0.74999         n=99999     time=52.167 sec
```

method#1 using fix function

```
threshold=0.74999         n=99999     time=0.005 sec
threshold=0.74999999      n=101554197 time=1.077 sec
threshold=0.7499999936263 n=134217004 time=1.407 sec
```

method#2 working backwards

```
threshold=0.74999         n=99999     time=0.026 sec
threshold=0.74999999      n=101554197 time=21.523 sec
threshold=0.7499999936263 n=134217004 time=25.247 sec
```

method#3 imperative way

```
threshold=0.74999         n=99999     time=0.008 sec
threshold=0.74999999      n=101554197 time=2.460 sec
threshold=0.7499999936263 n=134217004 time=3.254 sec
```

ReRe:
I noticed that whatever implementation I used (fix, imperative way, or recursive way), if the threshold is larger than 0.7499999936264... it never ends.. in order for f(n) to be larger than 0.7499999936264, I thought we just needed to compute the terms up to 150,000,000 since ![f(n)=\frac_{3n^2+5n}^{4n^2+12n+8}]. I used Integer instead of Int, but it did not help either. Is there any reason why it does not finish if I set the threshold larger than 0.7499999936264 ...?

Comment: I would probably write the it with explicit recursion. That can look pretty clean here, I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially explicit recursion, but I like `fix` for loops like this:

```
import Data.Function (fix)

term k = 1.0 / (k*k+2.0*k)

main = print $ fix (\f total k ->
                      let new = total + term k
                      in if new >= 2.99/4.0 then k else f new (k+1)
                   ) 0 1
```

Comment: What does `fix` do?

Answer (score 7):

I like to work backwards in these sort of situations:

```
main = print k where
  k = 1 + length (takeWhile (< (2.99/4)) partialSums)
  partialSums = scanl1 (+) terms
  terms = [ 1.0/(k*k+2.0*k) | k <- [1..] ]
```

How this works:

`terms` is an infinite list, but since Haskell is lazy, we'll only calculate as much of each term as we demand:

```
λ terms = [ 1.0/(k*k+2.0*k) | k <- [1..] ] :: [Double]
λ take 5 terms
[0.3333333333333333,0.125,6.666666666666667e-2,4.1666666666666664e-2,2.857142857142857e-2]
λ :p terms
terms = 0.3333333333333333 : 0.125 : 6.666666666666667e-2 :
        4.1666666666666664e-2 : 2.857142857142857e-2 : (_t5::[Double])
```

`partialSums` is another infinite list, based on the contents of `terms` (using [`scanl1`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:scanl1)). It lets us amortize the work that you do computing `termSum`:

```
λ partialSums = scanl1 (+) terms
λ take 5 partialSums 
[0.3333333333333333,0.4583333333333333,0.525,0.5666666666666667,0.5952380952380952]
```

The [`takeWhile (< (2.99/4))`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:takeWhile) then determines how many terms of `partialSums` we need to generate and thereby how many terms of
`terms` we need to generate:

```
λ length (takeWhile (< (2.99/4)) partialSums)
398
```

If we check, we can see that the sum of the first 398 `terms` are less than `2.99 / 4`, but the 399th bumps it over:

```
λ sum (take 398 terms) < 2.99/4
True
λ sum (take 399 terms) < 2.99/4
False
```

Or, equivalently that the 397th partial sum (0-based index) is less than the target and that the 398th is not:

```
λ partialSums !! 397 < 2.99/4
True
λ partialSums !! 398 < 2.99/4
False
```

Comment: Minor nit: you want `k+1`, not `k`, since you are dropping the first element for which the term is greater than or equal to 2.99/4.

Answer (score 5):

> It's a simple and easy stuff if I use another language, like c/c++

Well, let's do it in the same way, then.

```
import Prelude hiding (break)
import Data.IORef
import Control.Monad.Cont
import Data.Foldable
import Control.Monad (when)

-- long double term(int k) { return 1.0/(k*k+2.0*k); }
term :: Int -> Double
term k = 1.0/(k'*k'+2.0*k')
   where k' = fromIntegral k

-- int main() {
main :: IO ()
main = flip runContT return $ do
   -- long double total = 0.0;
   total <- lift $ newIORef (0.0 :: Double)
   -- for (int k=1;;k++) {
   callCC $ \break ->
      for_ [1..] $ \k -> do
         -- total += term(k);
         lift $ modifyIORef total (+ term k)
         -- if (total>=2.99/4.0) {
         totalV <- lift $ readIORef total
         when (totalV >= 2.99/4.0) $ do
            -- std::cout << k << std::endl;
            lift $ print k
            -- break;
            break ()
```

Yes, the above is more of a joke than a serious answer. Still, it's nice to see that, at least in theory, it is possible to write imperative code in Haskell.

It just leads to non-idiomatic Haskell, which is not that much harder to read or write than the original code. After all, what's a `callCC` or two between friends? :-P

Comment: For the curious: continuations are basically FP's version of `goto`. `callCC` introduces a "label"; it passes a continuation to its argument, and when that continuation is called ("goto") with some argument `x`, control jumps to after the `callCC`, and the value of `x` is returned.

Comment: That is a nice joke. But this mucking about with `IORef` seems like inefficient overkill. Why not use `ContT` with `State`? Oh, I guess that would get in the way of the `print` in the punchline....

Comment: @dfeuer I agree. I needed IO for the `print`. I could have used `ContT+StateT+IO`, I think. Refs are indeed overkill for this, but I wanted to show a very general (even if not very elegant) way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that explicit recursion is the simplest way to write this but using fix is confusing to all but very sophisticated programmers. Thus:

```
f :: Int       
f =
  f' 1 0
  where
    f' k tot
      | tot >= (2.99 / 4.0) = k - 1
      | otherwise           = f' (k + 1) (tot + term)
      where
        term = 1.0 / fromIntegral (k * k + 2 * k)
```

Using the higher order function until may be seen as closer to the C++ code. Thus

```
fh :: Int       
fh =
  fk - 1
  where
    (fk, ft)     =  until ((>= (2.99 / 4.0)) . snd) fh' (1, 0)
    fh' (k, tot) = (k + 1, tot + term)
      where
        term = 1.0 / fromIntegral (k * k + 2 * k)
```

Also the break in the C++ code is superfluous as that code can be written as

```
long double term(int k) { return 1.0/(k*k+2.0*k); }
int main() {
    long double total = 0.0;
    int k;
    for (k=1;total<2.99/4.0;k++) {
        total += term(k);
    }
    std::cout << k - 1 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Finally wrt why computing the terms up to 150,000,000 doesn't give you a result greater than 0.7499999936264 this in inherent to floating point arithmetic. Adding a very small term to a relatively large total doesn't change the total:

```
λ> term k = 1.0 / fromIntegral (k * k + 2 * k)
λ> term 150000000
4.444444385185186e-17
λ> (2.99 / 4.0) + it == (2.99 / 4.0)
True
```

To avoid this you have to add the terms in reverse order, from the smallest to the largest.